# How can i center the searchbar vertically?

Tags: html, css

.searchbar is my background for the searchbar, but i don't know how to center my searchbar to his background vertically.

Here is my CSS

```
.searchbar {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: lightgray;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
.searchbar input[type="text"] {
color: black;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 50%;
height: 40px;
font-size: 20px;
align-self: center;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here is the html

```
<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>
```

Comment: give us some html code as well

Comment: did you try margin: auto?

Comment: add to `.searchbar` `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: Regarding that searchbar's height is 100px, you should add "margin: auto" and "margin-top:30px" to the input.

Comment: You can also add instead ``display: flex; justify-content: center;`` to the searchbar

Comment: Thanks Greg it "display: flex; align-items: center;" actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.searchbar {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: lightgray;
text-align: center;

}
.searchbar input[type="text"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: block;
color: black;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 50%;
height: 40px;
font-size: 20px;
align-self: center;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
}


<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually works

```
.searchbar {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: lightgray;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.searchbar input[type="text"] {
color: black;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 50%;
height: 40px;
font-size: 20px;
align-self: center;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 50px;
border: none;
margin: auto;
}
```